# Building an array in PHP for CURL Post

Tags: php, arrays, curl

How do you build an array for a curl post in php without overwriting the previous field?  The headers show me the following in the post:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price[][unit]"

One
-----------------------------122371200014463
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price[][price]"

50
-----------------------------122371200014463
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price[][unit]"

Two
-----------------------------122371200014463
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price[][price]"

95
-----------------------------122371200014463
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price[][unit]"

Three
-----------------------------122371200014463
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="price[][price]"
140
```

I keep overwriting the previous item when I try to build the array like this:

```
$postPrice['price[][unit]']   =  'One';
$postPrice['price[][price]']   =  $one;
$postPrice['price[][unit]']   =  'Two';
$postPrice['price[][price]']   =  $two;
$postPrice['price[][unit]']   =  'Three';
$postPrice['price[][price]']   =  $three;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$fields = array(
            'price[][unit]' => "One",
            'price[][price]' => $one
            )
        );
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
```

then:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
```

Comment: This still overwrites the previous item in the array.

Comment: Do you control the incoming post ?

Comment: No, posting this to another website.